# Como pegar as 10 palavras mais frequentes de em array?

Tags: python

Preciso saber como pegar as dez palavras mais frequentes.

Esse código pega todas as palavras de um texto e guarda quantas vezes ela ocorreu.

```
if len(palavra) > 0:
   if palavra in conjunto:
     qtd = conjunto[palavra]
     qtd += 1
     conjunto[palavra] = qtd
  else:
     conjunto[palavra]
```

Como faço para devolver somente as 10 ocorrências mais frequentes?

Answer (score 6):

([TL;DR](https://repl.it/JJHZ/1))

### Collections:

```
import collections

# Lista de palavras
words = ['Banana', 'Maçã','Laranja', 
'Melão','Uva','Abacaxi','Abacate','Pimenta','Banana', 
'Maçã','Banana','Melão','Banana','Uva','Abacaxi','Fake','Fake']

# Contador para as ocorrencias de cada palavra
c = collections.Counter(words)

print (c)
Counter({'Banana': 4, 'Maçã': 2, 'Melão': 2, 'Uva': 2, 'Abacaxi': 2, 'Fake': 2, 
'Laranja': 1, 'Abacate': 1, 'Pimenta': 1})


# As 3 palavras mais frequentes
c.most_common(3)
[('Banana', 4), ('Melão', 2), ('Uva', 2)]
```

[Execute o código no repl.it.](https://repl.it/JJHZ/1)